# SSO on salesforce only works for certain users

Tags: apex, sandbox, single-sign-on, production

I just started with SSO on salesforce, I made my configuration on one of our sandboxes, the problem is that when I test the SSO connection or when I add a new user on the sandbox, it works well but when another user who already has an account in production and on the sandbox tests, it does not work.

They have this error

> "we can't log you in because of an issue with single sign-on, contact your salesforce administration"

I use the federation ID configuration  in my SSO configuration I checked for users who can't log in and they have the same Username on the sandbox as on the production.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please check if the federation id is present on the existing users in Salesforce. If it is not there you have to manually add it for all existing users.

Comment: I added the federation id manually for the existing users but I still get the error

Comment: Follow this [Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_saml_validation_errors.htm&type=5) article to debug the issue and findout the root cause.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked the connection history and the users for whom the sso connection does not work, use the connection type "Application" while for the users for whom it works, they use the connection type "SAML Sfdc initiated sso".
However I added the federation ID manually for the old users

Comment: Please check this [SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/333662/single-sign-on-login-type-issue) link. It sounds similar to yours.

Comment: I already enabled this setting "Make Federation ID case insensitive" but still get this error. On ADFS, should I change the claims?My claim currently are for incoming UPN and for outgoing Name ID

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour). Comments should not be used for a discussion, you should edit your question instead. Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

```
Modify Claim on AD FS server
LDAP attributes Outgoing claim
UPN Name ID
E-mail-Adresses Name ID
```